# ES6 in eslint sublime text

Tags: javascript, sublimetext, eslint

I set up **eslint** with **sublimeLinter** and it works fine, but I want to use some **ES6** goodness like *block-scope* (`let`, `const`). When I use them `eslint` identifies that as reserved word and thus error. How can I add in settings to ignore that in **sublime text** ?

Comment: You'll have to [configure eslint](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring) to enable ES6 features. "*By default, ESLint supports only ECMAScript 5 syntax.*"

Comment: Can you share your eslintrc file?

Comment: where to find that ?

Comment: @user3448600 It would typically be in the top directory of your project. If it doesn't have one yet, you'll want to create it. Or, as the docs mention, you can specify settings under a `"eslintConfig"` key if it has a `package.json`.

Comment: Yep, thanks. It works now. I was thinking that I need to set something in sublime setting user or something like that. I just created `package.json` and paste `json` from ESLint page and works now.